# what does this ruby do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
unless (place =~ /^\./) == 0
```

I know the unless is like `if not` but what about the condtional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It checks if the string `place` starts with a period `.`.

Consider this:

```
p ('.foo' =~ /^\./) == 0 # => true
p ('foo' =~ /^\./) == 0 # => false
```

In this case, it wouldn't be necessary to use `== 0`. `place =~ /^\./` would suffice as a condition:

```
p '.foo' =~ /^\./ # => 0 # 0 evaluates to true in Ruby conditions
p 'foo' =~ /^\./ # => nil
```

EDIT: `/^\./` is a regular expression. The start and end slashes denotes that it *is* a regular expression, leaving the important bit to `^\.`. The first character, `^` marks "start of string/line" and `\.` is the *literal* character `.`, as the dot character is normally considered a special character in regular expressions.

To read more about regular expressions, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or the excellent [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) website.

Comment: How does it do that ...what does =~ /^\./ mean

Comment: `=~` is for regular expression matching....`^` means start of string...and `\.` is for the period (which is a special character, hence has to be escaped)....the expression is enclosed within `/<exp>/`

Comment: It's not necessary to use a regexp at all. `place.start_with? '.'` is perfectly sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

`=~` means matches regex

`/^\./` is a regular expression:

`/.../` are the delimiters for the regex

`^` matches the start of the string or of a line (`\A` matches the start of the string only)

`\.` matches a literal .

Comment: `^` matches the start of a line or a string. `\A` matches the start of a string.